# Why Vue2 doesn't rerender component after props changed?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, rerender

Here is my problem:
I have an parent component (VisualCard.vue)

There are a code, where I pass props.

For example, I created a new component(TestComponent), which RERENDER component after props changed, but Visual Component doesn't

```
<Visual :vis='vis' :visualType='visualType' :key='visIdx'/>
<TestComponent :vis="vis.editorText"/>
```

Now I will show you a code of Visual Component

```html
export default class Visual extends BaseMixin {
  @Prop({default: {}}) visualType;
  @Prop() vis;
  @Prop({default: 3}) visIdx;

  mounted() {
    console.log(this.vis)
  }

  @Watch('$props', {deep:true, immediate: true})
  onChanged(val) {
    console.log(val)
  }
}
```

As you can see, there is an Vue Class Component, i tried to search some information about rerenders at class component, but i didn't find. I hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: Your component template does not depend on any of the props - there is no reason for Vue to rerender it. If you want to force a rerendering - you should change/update the `visIdx` in the `:key` prop in the parent component.

Comment: I got you, thanks